# PHP Convert a semicolon (;) with text 'OR'

Tags: php

I have a string which can be

```
$keywords = "val";
```

OR

```
$keywords = "val;";
```

OR

```
$keywords = "val1; val2;";
```

OR

```
$keywords = "val1; val2";
```

I want to iterate through this string getting each item which are -> `val` (in first example) and -> `val1` AND `val2` in the second (without the semicolon or the semicolon in the end). Each semicolon has changed with OR .

```
Expected Result:

val1 OR val2

OR 

val
```

I was thinking of;

1. Replace the semicolon (if any) in the end.
2. If there is semicolon (;), split-explode using "OR " and iterate through.
3. If not, only one item so just use it.

Is this the right way of doing it?

I am new to PHP and trying to learn best practices and best ways of solving the issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone pls help me?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right. You want the possibility of a missing semi-colon. And if the string has two `val` then you want an `OR` between them. Is that accurate?

Comment: just explode from `;` than loop through it and than you can do what you want in if condition

Comment: `$string = trim($keywords,";");
 $str = preg_replace("/(?<!\&gt);/", " OR", $string);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try handling this using `preg_replace`:

```
$keywords = "val1; val2;";
$output = rtrim(preg_replace("/;(?!$)\s*/", " OR ", $keywords), ";");
echo $keywords . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
val1; val2;
val1 OR val2
```

The regex pattern `;(?!$)\s*` targets all semicolons *other* than the final semicolon, plus any optional whitespace, and replaces with `OR`.  Then, we use `rtrim()` to remove the final semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Another method without `preg_replace` using [explode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and  [implode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$array = explode(";", $keywords);

if (end($array) == null) {
    array_pop($array);
}

$keywords = implode(" OR", $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use `preg_match` to find all words leading up to a `;` or end-of-line:

```
preg_match_all('/\w+(?=;|$)/', $keywords, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output will be an array with all the matching values, e.g. for `$keywords = "val1; val2";` it will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => val1
    [1] => val2
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tL3TH)

If you want to get an `OR` expression, using those values, just use

```
echo implode(' OR ', $matches[0]) . "\n";
```

which will give e.g. `val1 OR val2`.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DYc3D)

Comment: @SanjuMenon I'm not sure I completely answered your question. See my edit to get a logical expression (`val1 or val2`) out of the result.

Answer (score 0):

A possible second non-regex solution:

```
    $intermediate = str_replace(";", "", $keywords);
    $tokens = explode(" ", $intermediate);
    $result = join(" OR ", $tokens);
```

Provided there is no repeated white space.